# Why I get warning FileAge deprecated

Tags: delphi

I am trying to use the function `FileAge` to get file date and time but I get warning in Delphi 10.3 that this function was deprecated so what I should use ? I am going to use for both Windows and OS X. I use it like this:

```
var
fileDate: Integer;
Begin

  fileDate := FileAge(path + fileName);

end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Documentation:](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.FileAge) Note: The first overloaded version of FileAge is deprecated. Use the second version of FileAge instead.

That second version, also reading that same page, is the version that returns a TDateTime in the out parameter, so you can use it like this:

```
var
  FileDateTime: TDateTime;
Begin
  FileAge(path + fileName, FileDateTime);
```

The name of the function is a bit weird, though. The suggested overload returns the datetime of the file, which you have to subtract from the current date time to get the actual age, so personally I would have opted to deprecate the function in favor of a function with a different name.. Then again, the original function had the same issue.

You could have a look at [`TFile.GetCreationTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.IOUtils.TFile) and related functions. I think that name is a bit more clear. But that's up to you, of course.

Comment: Thanks so in the new function I have to subtract from current date time to get the actual age ?

Comment: Jup. A TDateTime is actually a double representing a number of days, including fractions for the time. So you can simply subtract two of them to get the age in days. You can also use one of the functions from `System.DateUtils` for that. For instance, if you use `SecondsBetween`, you get the age in seconds, which is would you also could have gotten from the old function. Note that the old function also gave the file date (just as a timestamp), not the actual file age.